# How to find the unique row with the largest column value?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database where entries are sorted like this:

```
| ID | length | breadth | height | time |
   1     10        20       30      123
   1     10        20       15      432 
   2      4         2        7      543 
   2      4         2        8      234
```

As you see, the height column can vary over time. I want to get the entry with the largest height, for every unique ID in my database. Is there some way to do this in one single query, instead of looping through all id's with something like this

```
for x in ids:

    SELECT length, breadth, height FROM table WHERE id = x ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but what about:

Select id,length,breadth, MAX(height) from table group by id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(height) FROM table GROUP BY ID
```